# amazon beans talk docker Failed to build Docker image aws_beanstalk/staging-app not a directory

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I want run my Java application in Amazon Beans talk within Docker, I zip Dockerfile, my app and bash script into archive and upload to beanstalk but during build I get error:

```
Step 2 : COPY run /opt
  time="2017-02-07T16:42:40Z" level="info" msg="stat /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/823f97180373b7f268e72b3a5daf0f965feb2c7aa9d3537cf845a36e2dfac80a/rootfs/opt/run: not a directory" 
  Failed to build Docker image aws_beanstalk/staging-app: ="info" msg="stat /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/823f97180373b7f268e72b3a5daf0f965feb2c7aa9d3537cf845a36e2dfac80a/rootfs/opt/run: not a directory" .
```

On my local computer docker build and run works fine.
My Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
MAINTAINER Dev

COPY run /opt
COPY app.war /opt

EXPOSE 8081

CMD ["/opt/run"]
```

Thanks for help

Comment: Where is the `run` file/folder ?

Comment: run file in one zip with Dockerfile and app.war